# плавное открытие и закрытие попапа

Tags: css

```js
const editButton = document.querySelector('.profile__edit-Button')
const popupClose = document.querySelector('.popup__close')
const popupSave = document.querySelector('.popup__input-save')
const popupName = document.querySelector('.popup__field_name')
const popupJob = document.querySelector('.popup__field_job')
const fullname = document.querySelector('.profile__full-name')
const jobs = document.querySelector('.profile__jobs')
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup')
const formSubmit = document.querySelector('.popup__form')
const addButton = document.querySelector('.profile__add-Button')

function openPopup() { //открытие popup
    popup.classList.add('popup_opened');
}

function closePopup() { //закрытие popup
    popup.classList.remove('popup_opened');
}

editButton.addEventListener('click', openPopup);
popupClose.addEventListener('click', closePopup);
```

```css
.popup__close {
    border: none;
    background: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    right: -35px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0;
}

.popup__close:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.popup__container {
    max-width: 430px;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 34px 36px 36px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup__field {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.popup__heading {
    max-width: 330px;
    margin: 0 0 54px 0;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 29px;
}

.popup__input-container {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 54px;
}

.popup__input-save {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
}

.popup__input-save:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.profile__edit-Button {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: unset;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 19px 0 0 17px;
    background: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.profile__edit-Button:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popup {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.popup_opened {
    display: flex;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button class="profile__edit-Button" type="button"></button>
<div class="popup">
            <div class="popup__container">
                <form class="popup__form" name="reprofile" method="GET" action="#">
                    <h2 class="popup__heading">Редактировать профиль</h2>
                    <fieldset class="popup__input-container">
                        <input type="text" name="profile" required placeholder="Имя и фамилия"
                            class="popup__field popup__field_name">
                        <input type="text" name="job" required placeholder="Должность"
                            class="popup__field popup__field_job">
                    </fieldset>
                    <button class="popup__input-save" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
                    <button class="popup__close" type="button"></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать плавное открытие и закрытие попапа
вроде прописал все как надо

Comment: дисплай не анимируется -

Comment: display в анимации не применяйте - сделали его флексом и пускай так и будет - visibility + opacity хватит

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо, я и не знал , что displey none не работает

Comment: Яндекс.практикум))) Великая вещь. У Вас не у одного проблема с сайтом "Mesto"

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через мгновенное изменение высоты, например. И `opacity`.

```css
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.element + .element{
  height: 0;
  transition-property: opacity, height;
  transition-duration: 1s, 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.element:hover + .element{
  height: 100px;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

```js
const editButton = document.querySelector('.profile__edit-Button')
const popupClose = document.querySelector('.popup__close')
const popupSave = document.querySelector('.popup__input-save')
const popupName = document.querySelector('.popup__field_name')
const popupJob = document.querySelector('.popup__field_job')
const fullname = document.querySelector('.profile__full-name')
const jobs = document.querySelector('.profile__jobs')
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup')
const formSubmit = document.querySelector('.popup__form')
const addButton = document.querySelector('.profile__add-Button')

function openPopup() { //открытие popup
  popup.classList.add('popup_opened');
}

function closePopup() { //закрытие popup
  popup.classList.remove('popup_opened');
}

editButton.addEventListener('click', openPopup);
popupClose.addEventListener('click', closePopup);
```

```css
.popup__close {
  border: none;
  background: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  right: -35px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
}

.popup__close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.popup__container {
  max-width: 430px;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 34px 36px 36px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup__field {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.popup__heading {
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 0 0 54px 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 29px;
}

.popup__input-container {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 54px;
}

.popup__input-save {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.popup__input-save:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.profile__edit-Button {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: unset;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 19px 0 0 17px;
  background: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.profile__edit-Button:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup {
  display: flex;
  height: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity, height;
  transition-duration: 1s, 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 1s;
}

.popup_opened {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
}
```

```html
<button class="profile__edit-Button" type="button"></button>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <form class="popup__form" name="reprofile" method="GET" action="#">
      <h2 class="popup__heading">Редактировать профиль</h2>
      <fieldset class="popup__input-container">
        <input type="text" name="profile" required placeholder="Имя и фамилия" class="popup__field popup__field_name">
        <input type="text" name="job" required placeholder="Должность" class="popup__field popup__field_job">
      </fieldset>
      <button class="popup__input-save" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
      <button class="popup__close" type="button"></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы хоть бы пример посмотрели бы - что он делает

Comment: @MaximLensky, я немного не понимаю, по-моему он пытается сделать анимацию открытия?

Comment: вот именно ..открытие а не изменение высоты

Comment: Вы успеваете заметить изменение высоты?)

Comment: нет ....просто опяцити срабатывает

Comment: Я не настаиваю, что решение верное, но суть претензии я тоже не понимаю.

Comment: второй ответ верный , первый ответ нет так как он не отвечает на вопрос - в вопросе плавное появление блока а не изменение высоты и  у меня не претензия а просто пояснение и в конце концов + я поставил а не минус